# How to download file with asp.net on buttton's onClick event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a String variable (in C#) that contain the full path of PDF file on my server 
(like that "~/doc/help.pdf").

I want that in click on button, this file will download to the client computer.

I created a button and made onClick event in C#. Now, which code should I write to do that?

Comment: Is that an asp button or just a html button?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: it's an asp button , and on click it's go to the event..
I want the it's download the file in this path , but stay in the same Location.

Comment: I've added the server-side part. If you have an ASP.NET button tell so, you'll be able to do this easier.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this.

```
private void Button1_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=help.pdf");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/doc/help.pdf"));
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: HI, i try that but when I click the button nothing happen.
I check with debbuger and it's enter to the event and run on this lines..but don't start the download..
(x contain the path)
 protected void DownloadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String x = downfilename.InnerText;
            Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=help.pdf");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(x));
            Response.End();

        }

Comment: try removing the last line `Response.End();`

Comment: removed. but still nothing happen. :

Comment: I've created a dummy website. download it and test
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=gffc91f2a48bb8d8099945028054060f5b0cabb889

Comment: Thanks!! The problem was that I placed my button into UpdatePanel , not I put it outside the element and it's work. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any way to be notified on the original client page that the download completed (failed or success)?

Answer (score 3):

Try this code on your `btn_Click`:

```
Response.Redirect("~/doc/link.pdf");
```

Comment: I get an "unsafe redirect" error when using this line only.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following to be placed into your button click event code.

This will provide the user with a popup to download the file. I've tested it thoroughly and use it in production code.

```
void btnDownloadFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string strLocalFilePath = "~/doc/help.pdf";
    string fileName = "help.pdf";

    Response.Clear();

    Stream iStream = null;

    const int bufferSize = 64 * 1024;

    byte[] buffer = new Byte[bufferSize];

    int length;

    long dataToRead;

    try
    {
        iStream = new FileStream(strLocalFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        dataToRead = iStream.Length;
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);

        while (dataToRead > 0)
        {
            if (Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                Response.Flush();
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                dataToRead = dataToRead - length;
            }
            else
            {
                //prevent infinate loop on disconnect
                dataToRead = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Your exception handling here
    }
    finally
    {
        if (iStream != null)
        {
            iStream.Close();
        }
        Response.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With an ASP button:

```
button.OnClientClick = string.Format("javascript:window.location='{0}'", pdfLink);
```

The logic behind this is here: [Client-side click](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_button_onclientclick.asp)

This will not reload the page and do a post-back, it will just navigate to the PDF which will be displayed in the browser.

---

Set the button's onclick event to this scriptlet:

```
onclick="javascript:window.location='/doc/help.pdf'"
```

To create that server-side:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:window.location='<%=PDFLink %>'" />
```

Where PDFLink is a string property in the code behind:

```
public string PDFLink
{
    get
    {
        return "/doc/link.pdf";
    }
}
```

From here it should be trivial to take the string from the database and render it absolute if need be.

Comment: thanks but it should be on the server side cause I get the file Path from the DB. (just gave an example with the help.pdf , it can change)

Comment: hi, the 'button.OnClientClick' , work, but it's open the pdf in the browser.. and I want it download to computer..maybe you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
 string path;
            string filename = "Page-3" + ".Pdf";
            path = "~/H/Emp/" + filename.ToString();
            Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename.ToString());
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(path));
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=File_Name.pdf");

Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("Folder_Name/File_Name.pdf"));

Response.End();
```